# Gridview displays first record only

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, datagridview

In my webpage, I am able to retrieve all records successfully. I am using a drop down list to filter the records based on the different "status". However, it only displays the first retrieved record.There were no exceptions or error. When I run the query in my database(to test my sql statement) there were 3 retrieved records. I am still unable to identify what went wrong in my codes.

I am working on a three-tier web application.

Here are my codes for the presentation layer,

```
 protected void ddl_status_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string status = ddl_status.SelectedItem.ToString();

            //Default
            if (status == "Show All Submissions")
            {
                gv_combinedEntries.Visible = true;
                SubmissionBLL sBLL = new SubmissionBLL();

                //Call getAllStudent() method in StudentBLL
                List<Submission> subAll = new List<Submission>();

                subAll = sBLL.getAllSub();

                gv_combinedEntries.DataSource = subAll;
                gv_combinedEntries.DataBind();
            }

            else 
            {
                SubmissionBLL subStatus = new SubmissionBLL();
                List<Submission> subList = new List<Submission>();
                subList = subStatus.getStatusList(status);
                gv_combinedEntries.DataSource = subList;
                gv_combinedEntries.DataBind();
            }
    }
```

Business Logic Layer :

```
public List<Submission> getStatusList(string statusPick)
{
        List<Submission> specificStatus = new List<Submission>();
        Submission sub2 = new Submission();
        specificStatus = sub2.getStatusNewList(statusPick);
        return specificStatus;
 }
```

Data Access Layer :

```
 public List<Submission> getStatusNewList(string statusSelected)
    {
        List<Submission> subStatus = new List<Submission>();
        string Id, School, TeamName, submissionDate, status;

        string queryStr = "SELECT s.Id,c.School,c.TeamName,s.submissionDate,
        c.submissionStatus FROM TeamSubmission s INNER JOIN Competition c
        ON c.teamUsername = s.username WHERE submissionStatus = @enterStatus";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enterStatus", statusSelected);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            Id = dr["Id"].ToString();
            School = dr["School"].ToString();
            TeamName = dr["TeamName"].ToString();
            submissionDate = dr["submissionDate"].ToString();
            status = dr["submissionStatus"].ToString();

            subStatus.Add(new Submission(Id, School, TeamName, submissionDate, status));
        }

        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();

        return subStatus;
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code and verified that 'subList' or 'subAll' have more than one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your **if (dr.Read())** statement to a while (dr.Read())

```
 while (dr.Read())
        {
            Id = dr["Id"].ToString();
            School = dr["School"].ToString();
            TeamName = dr["TeamName"].ToString();
            submissionDate = dr["submissionDate"].ToString();
            status = dr["submissionStatus"].ToString();

            subStatus.Add(new Submission(Id, School, TeamName, submissionDate, status));
        }
```